# Kafka enable.auto.commit false in combination with commitSync()

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am having a scenario where the `enable.auto.commit` is set to `false`. For every `poll()` the records obtained are offloaded to a `threadPoolExecutor`. And the `commitSync()` is happening out of the context. But, I doubt if this is the right way to handle as my thread pool may still be processing few message while i commit the messages.

```
while (true) {
 ConsumerRecords < String, NormalizedSyslogMessage > records = consumer.poll(100);
 Date startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 for (ConsumerRecord < String, NormalizedSyslogMessage > record: records) {
  NormalizedSyslogMessage normalizedMessage = record.value();
  normalizedSyslogMessageList.add(normalizedMessage);
 }
 Date endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
 long durationInMilliSec = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
 // execute process thread on message size equal to 5000 or timeout > 4000
 if (normalizedSyslogMessageList.size() == 5000) {
  CorrelationProcessThread correlationProcessThread = applicationContext
   .getBean(CorrelationProcessThread.class);
  List < NormalizedSyslogMessage > clonedNormalizedSyslogMessages = deepCopy(normalizedSyslogMessageList);
  correlationProcessThread.setNormalizedMessage(clonedNormalizedSyslogMessages);
  taskExecutor.execute(correlationProcessThread);
  normalizedSyslogMessageList.clear();
 }
 consumer.commitSync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are a couple of things to address here.

**First is Offsets being out of sync** - This is probably caused by either one of the following:

1. If the number of messages fetched by `poll()` does not take the size of the `normalizedSyslogMessageList` to 5000, the `commitSync()` will still run regardless of whether the current batch of messages has been processed or not.
2. If however, the size touches 5000 - because the processing is being done in a separate thread, the main consumer thread will never know whether the processing has been completed or not but... The `commitSync()` would run anyway committing the offsets.

**The second part (Which I believe is your actual concern/question)** - Whether or not this is the best way to handle this. I would say No because of point number 2 above i.e. the `correlationProcessThread` is  being invoked in a fire-and-forget manner here so you wouldn't know whe the processing of those messages would be completed for you to be able to safely commit the offsets.

Here's a statement from "Kafka's Definitive Guide" -

> It is important to remember that commitSync() will commit the latest
>   offset returned by poll(), so make sure you call commitSync() after
>   you are done processing all the records in the collection, or you risk
>   missing messages.

Point number 2 especially will be hard to fix because:

- Supplying the consumer reference to the threads in the pool will basically mean multiple threads trying to access one consumer instance ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274024/how-to-use-multi-thread-consumer-in-kafka-0-9-0) makes a mention of this approach and the issues - Mainly, Kafka Consumer NOT being Thread-Safe).
- Even if you try and get the status of the processing thread before committing offsets by using the `submit()` method instead of `execute()` in the `ExecutorService`, then you would need to make a blocking get() method call to the `correlationProcessThread`. So, you may not get a lot of benefit by processing in multiple threads.

**Options for fixing this**

*As I'm not aware of the your context and the exact requirement, I will only be able to suggest conceptual ideas but it might be worth considering*:

- breaking the consumer instances as per the processing they need to do and carrying out the processing in the same thread or
- you could explore the possibility of maintaining the offsets of the messages in a map (as and when they are processed) and then committing those specific offsets ([this method](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync(java.util.Map)))

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with what Lalit has mentioned. Currently i'm going through the same exact situation where my processing are happening in separate threads and consumer & producer in different threads. I've used a ConcurrentHashMap to be shared between producer and consumer threads which updates that a particular offset has been processed or not.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<OffsetAndMetadata, Boolean>
```

On the consumer side, a local LinkedHashMap can be used to maintain the order in which the records are consumed from Topic/Partition and do manual commit in the consumer thread itself.

```
LinkedHashMap<OffsetAndMetadata, TopicPartition>
```

You can refer to the following link, if your processing thread is maintaining any consumed record order.
[Transactions in Kafka](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/)

A point to mention in my approach, there will be chance that data will be duplicated in case of any failures.